# Minimize browser repainting: Simplest code for intersection in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, intersection-observer

I have this auto slide between 3 colors.

I'm using Js to toggle opacity and move to the next slide each time on loop.

Everything works well.

**https://codepen.io/cat999/pen/bGpjjpN**

the main issue is that I have **ANIMATION PERFORMANCE ISSUES**

I’ll soon find that animating constantly each images can cause devices to run really hot and become slow or unresponsive, especially when the animations have been running for a while.

This will hopefully be optimized in subsequent browser releases, but until then, I’ll just have to minimize browser repainting. I’ve found that using an IntersectionObserver works great, and allows us to stop the animations whenever the variable text is off-screen. But in that case, is not working.

```
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(function(entry) {
    // Pause/Play the animation
    if (entry.isIntersecting) entry.target.style.animationPlayState = "running"
    else entry.target.style.animationPlayState = "paused"
  });
});

var variableTexts = document.querySelectorAll(".promo-intro-slide");
variableTexts.forEach(function(el) { observer.observe(el); });
```

Could anyone out there help me to stop my animation with intersection observer?

Comment: where is `stopStart`?

Comment: Hi Will, any idea on what is should remove /add?

Comment: it's quite hard to work out what you're trying to do from your code pen. If you can trim it right back to the bare essentials I can help but currently it's too hard to understand what you're trying to do and what your problem is.